# Calling fragment from activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

I am trying to call a class whıch extends fragment from an activity class with `startActivity()` . It returns me cannot be cast to android.app.activity error. I am confused how can I open fragment vıew from activity.

Comment: You can not open fragment from an activity but you have to call a fragment using fragment manager and fragment transaction.

Comment: but I want to call a class which extends fragment. can fragment manager do this?

Comment: You question could do with a more descriptive title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the activity, you create an transaction to replace a fragment by another:

```
    FragmentSelectDate myFragment = new FragmentSelectDate();
    myFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.containerMain, myFragment,
                "FragmentSelectDate");
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
```

Comment: if you were not using supportFragment then call getFragmentManger()

Comment: both getsupportfragmentmanager and getfragmentmanager cannot be resolved sınce my first class extends activity. also what is R.id.containerMain ?

Comment: @user3834286, the activity where you use getSupportFragmentManager has to extend "FragmentActivity". R.id.containerMain is a  <FrameLayout>, that I placed in the Activity's layout (.XML). So the Activity has a layout (.XML), that holds a FrameLayout (the container for the fragment). You can have more fragments in 1 activity-layout)